# For Lopop Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to obtain the asset and its value from the result without the curly braces, I have tried to do it through various ways and I have not succeeded, could someone help me please?

The result I want to get is ASSET: bitcoin 43935

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import requests
import json
import urllib
 
 
 
base_url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/'
     
url = base_url + '/coins'
r = requests.get(url)
identifiers = r.json()
#print(identifiers)
symbol_id_map = {d['symbol']:d['id'] for d in identifiers}
#print(symbol_id_map)
symbols = ['BTC', 'ETH','USDT' ]
ids = [symbol_id_map[symbol.lower()] for symbol in symbols]
ids = ",".join(ids)
url = base_url + f'/simple/price?ids={ids}&vs_currencies=usd'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
print(type(r))
obj = r.json()
print(type(obj))
print(obj)
     
for key in sorted(obj):
    print("ASSET:",key, ':', obj[key])
```

This is the output:

```
{'bitcoin': {'usd': 43935}, 'ethereum': {'usd': 2923.98}, 'tether': {'usd': 0.999972}}
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
<class 'dict'>
{'bitcoin': {'usd': 43935}, 'ethereum': {'usd': 2923.98}, 'tether': {'usd': 0.999972}}
ASSET: bitcoin : {'usd': 43935}
ASSET: ethereum : {'usd': 2923.98}
ASSET: tether : {'usd': 0.999972}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a nested dictionary, I think something like this will get the result you are asking for:

```
for key,val in obj.items():
        for k,v in val.items():    
            print(f'ASSET: {key} {v}')
```

Output:

```
ASSET: bitcoin 43935
ASSET: ethereum 2923.98
ASSET: tether 0.999972
```

There may be a few ways to do this, but this is one way. F-strings are helpful in formatting the string output in the exact way you want it.

Comment: **Esa es la salida que esperaba. I am very grateful for your help**

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! Can you accept the answer when you get a chance?